# How to stop cells from indenting - shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath has no effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a plain (not grouped) tableView with custom cells, and when I hit the Edit button, the cells indent. I don't want that, I want the deletion sign to lay right on top of my cell.

I tried shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath and also cell.shouldIndentWhileEditin = NO; as well as cell.indentionLevel = -3, but both won't have any effect. Any idea why?

Could this be due to my setup? I followed [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGvs1XqTae0), and I also tried a setup like [Davyd suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915345/edit-mode-with-custom-cells), but the last did not only still indent my cells, it made it even worse, as the cells were indented, when I press Done.. and I can't get the background image to cover the whole cell...

So, anyone knows how to stop custom cells in a plain tableview from intending, while still showing the delete and move sign?

//EDIT:
btw, I build the custom cell in IB. I can take away the checkmark saying "Indent while Editing", it doesn't care. I can change the values for indention level and width, no effect. If i change the editing accessory, it happily displays it. 
Hope that helps..

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of research and trying pixel by pixel, it turned out, I needed to use `-(void)layoutSubviews` to "transit" from the original state to the original size.. If someone else ever needs to do that, here's my code, placed in my CustomCell.m:

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)aState
{
[super willTransitionToState:aState];
self.state = aState;
}


- (void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];
// no indent in edit mode
self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0,                                          
                                    self.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                    self.contentView.frame.size.width, 
                                    self.contentView.frame.size.height);

if (self.editing )        
{
    NSLog(@"subview");
    float indentPoints = self.indentationLevel * self.indentationWidth;

    switch (state) {
        case 3:
            self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(indentPoints,
                                                self.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                                self.contentView.frame.size.width +124,// - indentPoints, 
                                                self.contentView.frame.size.height);   

            break;
        case 2:
            // swipe action
            self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(indentPoints,
                                                self.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                                self.contentView.frame.size.width +75,// - indentPoints, 
                                                self.contentView.frame.size.height);   

            break;
        default:
            // state == 1, hit edit button
            self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(indentPoints,
                                                self.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                                self.contentView.frame.size.width +80,// - indentPoints, 
                                                self.contentView.frame.size.height);  
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 3):

None of the above works for me, but this did:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

This way your saying to the UITableView that you dont want any native styling when in edit mode, and instead you can take care of it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that the delegate method `tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:` is being called when you edit the cell?

The only time I used the `tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method
it worked fine.

```
// Override to prevent indentation of cells in editing mode (in theory)
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: shouldIndentWhileEditing gets called, but this will only work for grouped tableViews, mine is plain, and has to be :/

Comment: I tried the `shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath` delegate method with a plain table view on iOS 6, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the autoresizing mask of your content view or the elements inside your cell. The indent is because when your cell enters editing mode the content view is resized to show the accessories and the content moves with it.

It's hard to give specific advice without knowing what's in your cell, but you want to look at the fixed left or right margins.

Comment: My cell contains a button and two labels, but I also set an image to the cell.contentView.backgroundColor, which also shouldn't be indented. I tried various combinations of en- and disabled red lines in the size inspector in IB, and none had the desired effect by now. Did I miss the correct combination? Thank you.

Comment: Is it just the background image that isn't working, or the labels and buttons too? I had the opposite problem, I had a custom layout and I wanted it to indent but it didnt, and the autoresizing sorted it out for me.

Comment: The image, the buttons, as well as the labels do indent. And as I said, toggling the red lines has no effect :( I tried for the CustomCell, as well as for the button or labels. In fact, it looks like it indents my cell to the right, and than trims on the right side, for displaying the move sign.

Answer (score 0):

---

I had the same problem. The reason is: They're not indented but auto-resized. The remove button is shown an the cell's view (and its subviews) are resized.

Solution is: Set the autosizing behavior of the custom table cell's subviews (the labels or whatever you placed on it) in InterfaceBuilder/Xcode as you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that if you connect a UIView to the backgroundView outlet, it *doesn't move at all*. That combined with autoresizing flags is really all you need, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this on iOS 6.

The `shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath` delegate method now works on plain table view as well.

----Edited-----

Well, as it turned out, it doesn't indent only if `allowsMultipleSelection = YES`